# How to lock concurrent request verification in php session

Tags: php, security, session, redis, concurrency

I have a functionality to verify captcha in php. While loading captcha random text and storing into session.
And display the session text in an image format in the form asking user to fill captcha and submit, after submit, verifying submitted captcha value with the value, after verification unset session value.
If same value resubmit from with from, due to value not existing in data base,  result showing verification failed, which is fine.

Using the security tool, through intruder after loading the captcha, if we send 10's of concurrent request on same time, due to the same time, each request verifying with session and giving result. Due to concurrent requests on same time result giving as verify, ideally only with first request it should get verified and further requests should be failed at captcha.
How to control concurrent requests, ideally only first request will return success all other should be retunr verification failed.
How to achieve this? Technologies using php, using reddis to store session..

Looking for solution to restrict concurrent request and allow to verify one after another.

Comment: You could put the two database queries, one for the verification, and the other to unset the session value when the verification was successful, in one [transaction](https://redis.io/docs/interact/transactions/). That way only one concurrent request can successfully execute both.

Comment: No database is using, all the logics on session/ redis. When the request came on same times all checking happening simultaneously and all checks failing.

Comment: Then I guess you will have to enable session locking in your redis settings, because currently that appears to be off.